# Saving output of join query to a datatable

Tags: c#, join, datatable

I am attempting to join two datatables using a query in C#.

I have two datatables, `Crops` and `HailGridLatLon`.

Crops contains columns `hail_grid_id`, `value`, `count`, `year`.

`HailGridLatLon` contains columns `hail_grid_id`, `lat`, `lon`.

I need to extract the `lat` and `lon` values corresponding to each `hail_grid_id` in the `Crops` data table.

My problem is that after executing the join query, I need to save the resulting values for latitude and longitude into new columns in the `Crops` datatable.  Everything I have found regarding join queries and select clauses only ever prints the results to the console, never saves them at all.

Here is the query code I am running:

```
var results = from table1 in Crops.AsEnumerable()
                      join table2 in HailGridLatLon.AsEnumerable() on table1[0] equals table2[0]
                      select new
                      {
                          hail_grid_id = table1[0], value = table1[1], count = table1[2], year = table1[3], latitude = table2[1], longitude = table2[2]
                      };
```

I know that to print the values to the screen I would need this loop:

```
foreach (var item in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", item.hail_grid_id, item.value, item.count, item.year, item.latitude, item.longitude));
        }
```

But like I said, I need to save latitude and longitude in such a way that they can be added to a data table.  Or alternatively just save the information stored in results into a new data table.  Is there any way to do this?  I seem to basically have an object type "results", but is there a way to convert this to any other variable type, preferably a data table?

p.s. I know this can be done with nested for loops, but these tables are huge and such a method will take more than 24 hours to complete.

Comment: Could you write a query that joins the two table at the database level?

Comment: That is possibly an option in the future, however one of the databases is not yet complete and I am trying to get some code written that will perform the necessary analysis so it is ready to go when the database is finalized.  So my strong preference is to figure out a way to do it in c#.  I like the join method I am trying as it runs very quickly for a large set of data, but it is absolutely imperative that I be able to store the joined table in such a way that calculations can be performed using the stored values.